# Customer able to select Package of product

Tags: product, customer, package

How to give a option to customer, to select package option?

Options like

1. Normal Package
2. Extra Package [5% of product price]

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 simple products called "Normal Package" and "Extra package". 
And then make all your other products to be Configurable.
Each Configurable product will include 2 simple products mentioned above, and each Simple product will change (or not change) price of Configurable product

OR

you can also use "Custom option", applied inside each product.